# Java/android how to start an AsyncTask after 3 seconds of delay?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

How can an AsyncTask be started after a 3 second delay?

Comment: How important is it that the task persist through app restarts?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use Handler for that. Use postDelayed(Runnable, long) for that.

[Handler#postDelayed(Runnable, Long)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29)

Answer (score 18):

Using handlers as suggested in the other answers, the actual code is:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new MyAsyncTask().execute();
    }
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use this piece of code to run after a 3 sec delay.

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {          
    @Override
    public void run() {

        // run AsyncTask here.    


    }
}, 3000);
```

Comment: what if after 1sec application is closed? i mean the application is completely destroyed? will this timer still run after 3 sec... i am asking bcz my need is to run AsyncTask even if the app is closed....

Comment: No, it will not run. If you need to persist through app restarts, use alarms.

Answer (score 4):

Use Handler class, and define Runnable `handleMyAsyncTask` that will contain code executed after 3000 msec delay:

```
mHandler.postDelayed(handleMyAsyncTask, 1000*3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CountDownTimer.

```
  new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

           //do task which continuously updates

        }

        public void onFinish() {

           //Do your task
         
        }

    }.start();
```

3000 is total seconds and 1000 is timer tick on that time means on above case timer ticks 3 time.