# Simulate delay when button clicked

Tags: java, android

I do have a button and when this button is clicked I want to do some actions and revert them back, in lets to say 5 secs. Example, when Button A is clicked, TextA.Text becomes "Clicked" for 5 secs, in 5 secs the value of text should come back to its original. Here what I do have, but I feel that it is totally wrong way. The code that do delay:

```
diff=time2-time1;

            while (diff<5000) {
                //Log.d("Timer is", String.valueOf(diff));
                time2=System.currentTimeMillis();
                diff=time2-time1;
            }
```

so untill loop is working its simulate delay and after i do what i want. Any advice?

Comment: Didnt knew about this, i thought the most answers which will be rated they will be counted as an answer. Thanks for this info, in future I will.

Comment: You can go back to _all_ your old questions and accept the best answers there too, not just for future questions!

Comment: Definitely, I will do it right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), something like this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    void run() {
        // do something later
    }
}, 5000);
```

Edit: Note that this solution allows the main thread to continue during the delay - refreshing the GUI, handling activity changes (such as "Home" button) correctly, etc.  Using `Thread.sleep()` does not.

Comment: +1 Judging from the docs, I think this is better than `Thread.sleep`.

Comment: good one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038463/why-does-handlerpostdelay-make-ui-frozen

Comment: thanks, this is what i want. Simple, just for my level of knowledge. How efficient is this code? any risk that it makes thread to stop unexpectedly, when user works with other gui elements?

Answer (score 2):

You have a method to do that :

```
Thread.sleep(5000)
```

It can throw a InterruptedException, so you have to catch it.

Comment: dangit you beat me, I was gunna say that xD

Answer (score 2):

Busy loop is a bad idea - it eats your batteries alive. Perhaps [`Thread.sleep`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) would work better.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```
// First save the current value of Textbox in a variable 
String tmpVal = myEditText.getText();
// Now Setting of new Value for 2 seconds 
myEditText.setText ( "Clicked" );
// Sleeping for 5 seconds
try
{
     Thread.sleep(5000);
}
//Now Returning back to your old value
myEditText.setText ( tmpVal );
```

All the above code goes in to `public void onClick(View v)` method.

Comment: Which one is better this, thread.sleep or by using handler as in the above comment?

Comment: as per your usage, Threa.Sleep will better, as you have only one action to perform.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the view on Onclick and can use

```
@Override
public void onClick(final View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.button1) {

    if(isClikcalbe ){
isClikcalbe  = false;
      view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                // you code 
                 isClikcalbe = true;
            }
        }, 5000);
   }

    }
}
```

can also use bollean isClikcalbe to stop new click until get unable

Answer (score 0):

You might want considering AsyncTasks as a container where you do your job. Additionally, you can call Thread.sleep inside it. After you job is done can ask Handler object to change the caption.

Reason for doing it in AsyncTask instead of just sleeping the main thread is that your application doesn't "freeze". Here's how you could use it:

```
private class AsyncHttpRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            _jobHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    }

protected Handler _jobHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void dispatchMessage(Message msg) {
            // set the caption here
        }
    };
```