# Execution order in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, handlers

I have an Android code like:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result){            
parseJSON(result);
replaceResourceSegment();
dummyMethod();
}
```

My replaceresourceSegment(creates an intent) method takes some time to execute within which dummyMethod() gets called. Do I have a means to order the execution of methods or notify after a method gets completed in Android(like threads in Java)? Please suggest me, if I have to use a Handler or AsyncTask or Thread for accomplishing the same... Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you could use a handler and execute a method postdelayed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038463/why-does-handlerpostdelay-make-ui-frozen

Comment: Ya but I need some notification mechanism after the method replaceResourceSegment() completes. As the time taken to execute my method may vary.

Comment: I used startActivityForResult() and defined the dummyMethod() inside onActivityResult(). It worked :)

Comment: You can post that as answer and mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE) and defined the contents of dummymethod() in  onActivityResult(int requestCode, int ResultCode, Intent data).