# How to late thread run in android

Tags: android, performance

In my code I have a thread. You can see the code of thread,

```
public class MainAsyncHome extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String xml) {


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {


        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

        }


    }
```

I run this thread in my main activity onCreate method as following way

```
new MainAsyncHome().execute(null);
```

But I want to give time out for this thread. It means when main activity run I want late to run this thread. I know it can do using sleep method. But How I can late for running this thread just like that way.
I'm stuck with this problem.
pls give me answer. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run an async task for every x mins in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207362/how-to-run-an-async-task-for-every-x-mins-in-android)

Comment: how timeout is connected with delayed start ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally use `CountDownTimer`, suppose a 3 seconds of delay:

```
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

     }

     public void onFinish() {
         //do things, start your Task
         //remember we are still in the main thread!
     }
  }.start();
```

Get more info at:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Answer (score 4):

Use [Handler class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29), and define Runnable handleMyAsyncTask that will contain code executed after 3000 msec delay:

```
mHandler.postDelayed(MainAsyncHome, 1000*3); //Delay of three seconds
```

The answer is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177409/java-android-how-to-start-an-asynctask-after-3-seconds-of-delay).

To put it in the code:

```
private final static int INTERVAL = 1000 * 3; //3 seconds
Handler m_handler;

Runnable MainAsyncHome = new Runnable()
{
     @Override 
     public void run() {
          doSomething();
          m_handler.postDelayed(MainAsyncHome, INTERVAL);
     }
}

void startRepeatingTask()
{
    MainAsyncHome.run(); 
}

void stopRepeatingTask()
{
    mHandler.removeCallback(MainAsyncHome);
}
```

Hope it works.

Comment: People should learn about the Handler class. People should take the time to understand how to use and program the system before going ahead and dumping SO with misaddressed questions. Thanks for promoting the Handler it is absolutely vital for Android development!

Comment: got error message "The method removeCallback(Runnable) is undefined for the type Runnable". I want to create handler class sepereatly, Can't I put this code in mainActivity

Comment: Try replacing `mHandler.removeCallback(MainAsyncHome);` with `m_handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);`. If this works ok, I'll edit my reply.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CountDownTimer` like this.

Start your timer in **onCreate**.

```
CountDownTimer timer=new CountDownTimer(Delay,TimeIntervalToCallOnTick) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //start your asynctask
            }
        };
```