# Android how to Display Welcome message when touch mouse or keyboard

Tags: android, touch, android-alertdialog, ontouchlistener

When a user touch the mouse or keyboard, then the app display a message pic or text “Welcome to Kohat” for 3 seconds and go to sleep.
While in sleep mode, if no one touch the keyboard or mouse for 3 minutes. Then it start the message again.any help will be much appreciated.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use touch-event listener and onKeypress listener and display a Toast It May help You.

Comment: are you going to connect mouse or keyboard to an Android device!!! I am not able to get it.

Comment: @VishwasSharma This android app for TV devices names Noga devices,hope now u get my point..

Comment: @PrashantMishra thanks for ur reply..i implementing on touch listner and it's work fine and display the message,but now the problem is that if no one touch the keyboard or mouse for 3 minutes then it start message(at this point i am stuck),how i can implement this point?