# error in key event handler

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyevent, android-keypad

I tried to capture key event for android. Here is the source code i tried:

```
text.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "A Pressed!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

But it's doesn't work or show any error.
How can i handle the key event for android keyboard?

Comment: How can you get the pressed key event on `textview` click listener?

Comment: actually it's not a textview, it's edittext view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Software keyboards don't generate onKey events.  Only hardware keyboards do.  If you want to see changes from a software keyboard, use a TextWatcher on the view.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to use `TextChangedListener`, Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171234/androidhow-to-get-any-keypress-event-with-example/4171427#4171427), based on the text, do your work.